# No reply channel error, even if it is defined in the gateway

Tags: spring-integration

I have created a spring dsl gateway with request channel and reply channel. This gateway produces output.

```
@MessaginGateway
public interface Gateway{
@Gateway(requestChannel="reqChannel", replyChannel="replyChannel")
String sayHello(String name);
}
```

I am trying to test the output in unit testing. So I have created a bridge in my unit test context. And when i try to receive it from bridge channel, it is giving me "no output-channel or reply-channel header available" error.

I have created bridge like below.

```
@Bean
@BridgeFrom("replyChannel")
public QueueChannel bridgeOutput(){
return MessageChannels.queue.get();
}
```

In my test, I am sending message to the request channel  `reqChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Name").build());`  and I have tried to receive the reply by `bridgeOutput.receive(0)`. It is giving me the above error.

If i call sayHello() method directly, it is working fine. I am just trying to test the gateway, by directly putting message into the channel.

What I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

```
<int-enricher request-channel="gatewayRequestChannel" >
   <int-property name="name" expression="payload" />
</int-enricher>
```

In the above, i am putting message into the requestChannel and setting the property.  Instead of 'gatewayRequestChannel', can I call a java method there and set the return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that; the reply channel is inserted as a header by the gateway.

Your bridge is creating a second consumer on the reply channel.

If you want to simulate what the gateway is doing in a unit test, remove that bridge and use:

```
QueueChannel replyChannel = new QueueChannel();
reqChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Name")
    .setReplyChannel(replyChannel)
    .build());
Message<?> reply = replyChannel.receive(10000);
```

Inside the gateway, the `reply-channel` is bridged to the message header; that bridge is one consumer, your bridge is another.

**EDIT**

You are bypassing the enricher - you seem to have misunderstood the configuration of an enricher. The enricher is a special kind of gateway itself.

Use:

```
<int-enricher input-channel="enricherChannel" 
        request-channel="gatewayRequestChannel" >
    <int-property name="name" expression="payload" />
</int-enricher>
```

and send your test message to `enricherChannel`. The enricher acts as a gateway to the flow on `gatewayRequestChannel` and enriches the results from the results of that flow.

Comment: Thanks, One more issue i am facing is, i have implemented errorFlow from the errorChannel. So I have configured setErrorChannel() like you have explained above. But my error flow is not receiving the message, and exception is thrown out. What could be wrong.

Comment: The logic to handle the errors is built into the gateway; if you bypass it in your test it can't be invoked. Just setting the error channel in the message is not enough. It's not clear what you are trying to test here. It's best to just test your flow by calling the gateway.

Comment: Reason i want to do this way is someplaces like enricher we can give this gateway's request channel and get the reply and set the property. Is there anyother way to invoke gateway directly from enricher instead of using service activator?

Comment: You should not be sending to the gateway's request channel directly - you should always use the gateway. `... invoke gateway directly from enricher ...`. It's not clear what you mean, or what you are trying to do; please edit your question with more information and sample configuration.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the enricher; see my edit.